# Protractor xpath identification with lengthy xpath

Tags: javascript, testing, xpath, protractor, end-to-end

New to Protractor scripting.

Any feedback on why I am unable to find element in the stack trace based on this following run?

```
TempString = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("/html/body/section/div/form/section/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h3")).getText();
```

This is "monthly payment" field at the `mortgagecalculator.org` site.

Comment: I tried both single quotes and the double around the string; no luck.

Comment: Have you tried: `//*@id="calc"]/form/section/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h3`? This is what Chrome's element inspector gave me. In any case, I think you need a double forward slash at the beginning.

Comment: @IsaacLyman I think this is an overcomplication to have an xpath like this, check out my answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's a good way of doing it. I would like it noted that I personally never use xpath because it's so fragile--the slightest change of the page wipes out all your xpaths. I much prefer cleverly-made CSS paths. But your xpath should be pretty solid, since it finds wording that isn't likely to change.

Comment: @alecxe slow learning of protractor js syntax:  having trouble finding good source of documentation for "List" methods.  ie.  my script errors trying to traverse the array.....any thought?  see answer

Comment: @alecxe I recently used a List object of type <webelement> in a selenium junit test but I am having trouble with js in protractor script  ie.  my script below runs fine through the findElements line but I cannot traverse the array.  ps. non-angular web site thus browser.driver ref.

Comment: @ColtsFan please go through your questions and accept the answers if they deserve to be accepted (checkbox on left to the answer).

Answer (score 2):

[Make it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Rely on the "Monthly payment" text and get the [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling):

```
//span[contains(., "Monthly Payment")]/preceding-sibling::h3
```

---

Since there are two elements with "Monthly Payment" text, you can use [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) to get both and use `first()` and `last()` to get the desired one:

```
var monthlyPayments = element.all(by.xpath('//span[contains(., "Monthly Payment")]/preceding-sibling::h3'))

monthlyPayments.first().getText();  
monthlyPayments.last().getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[@value='Calculate']")).click();
        var TempStringList;
        var fTempString;
        var sTempString;

    //attempt to get everything on the page with span label Monthly     Payment - note there are two
    TempStringList = browser.driver.findElements(by.xpath('//span    [contains(., " Monthly Payment")]/preceding-sibling::h3'));
    //GOOD TO HERE ON RUN BUT PROBLEM BELOW WITH NAVIGATING THE     ARRAY LIST
    fTempString = TempStringList.first().getText();
```